# Nextjs image show 500 server error on first render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am encountering an issue on an application built using Nextjs and React and i use Next Image component to render images from external api. The app is working fine but on the first launch of the app the images seems broken and when inspecting browser console it shows 500 server error, however when clicking on the image link it works fine. I am unable to inspect the real problem behind this as it shows on first render only and when reloading the page the images shows.
Note that when using custom loader to return the image src directly it works fine but the images in this case not cached.
Can anyone have this issue before?

Comment: Have you configured nextjs to allow images from external domain?

Comment: Share the code how you are calling the images.

Comment: Yes i added the all domains and subdomains the image coming from, i think not the issue with the domains as i mentioned because it load the second time